# Typescript error with accessing jwt-decode object

Tags: typescript, jwt

I have installed `@types/jwt-decode` and I'm having trouble getting this to work.

```
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode'

...
let decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
console.log(decodedToken) // this works! I can see the full object
console.log(decodedToken.exp) // error Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)
```

Comment: I have no problem with your code (working with the package jsonwebtoken), as long as I provide a token that contains an `exp` claim. You didn't show us a token or the result of `console.log(decodedToken)`. Does it contain `exp`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The issue is `jwtDecode` is unaware of what is inside your token, as it could be anything. Because of this, it uses the type `unknown` to signify that result of the decoded JWT is, unknown.

To get around this you will need to create an `interface` describing what you expect to be in your JWT and tell `jwtDecode` to use it as the return type of the decoded token. You can do so like this:

```js
interface MyToken {
  name: string;
  exp: number;
  // whatever else is in the JWT.
}

const decodedToken = jwtDecode<MyToken>(token);
console.log(decodedToken.exp); // works!
```

Answer (score 19):

For v3.1.1, type definitions have been added recently.

```
import jwt_decode, { JwtPayload } from 'jwt-decode'

const decodedToken = jwt_decode<JwtPayload>(token)
```

Also added by @Martina in the comments section, parsing non-standard claims can be done also by extending a type on the JwtPayload interface for creating a custom jwt payload type such as:

```
type customJwtPayload = JwtPayload & { some_property: string };
```

and then,

```
const decodedToken = jwtDecode<customJwtPayload>(token);
```

Comment: thanks for this hint. to parse non standard claims I used it with extended type like this: type customJwtPaylod  = JwtPayload & {preferred_username:string};
 let decoded = jwt_decode<customJwtPaylod>(token);
 console.log(decoded.preferred_username);

Answer (score 1):

I have done this and worked for me.

```sh
yarn add jwt-decode
yarn add -D @types/jwt-decode
```

And this is the function that has been implemented for checking the token:

```js
import jwtDecode, { JetPayload } from 'jwt-decode'

const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
if (!token) return
const decodedToken: JwtPayload = jwtDecode(token);
if ((decodedToken?.exp as JwtPayload) < new Date().getTime()) {
  // code here
}
```

the snippet below is the one that worked for me, and remove the error when I was trying to validate `decodedToken.exp`

Comment: The decodedToken.exp will be in seconds since epoch time per RFC-7519 while getTime() will return milliseconds since epoch, so this code won't correctly check expiry time. Also, the exp value should be of type number | undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this error is solved if not then:

if you want to fetch/use data from Jwt then use **JwtPayload** as the version is Updated.

here is small example

```
var sid;
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token')!;
  const decoded: JwtPayload = jwt_decode(token);

sid = decoded?.exp;
```

> here I have stored expiry data to var sid

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
...
interface IDecodedToken {
  payload: IEmployeeInfo;
  iat: number;
  exp: number;
}

const decodedToken = (await verifyAccessToken(token)) as IDecodedToken;
const email = decodedToken?.payload?.email;
```