# I am getting a type: Unknown Error saying it not assignable to type on React/Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is the highlighted error on my payload, the payload in Session Action is highlighted to correct the errors

```
(property) ILoginUser.payload: {
    currentUser: LoginInfo;
}
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '{ currentUser: LoginInfo; }'.ts(2322)
```

**This is the highlighted error on my payload**

Session Action

```
export const login = (user: any) => async (dispatch: Dispatch<SessionActions>) => {

    try {
        const res = await SessionUtil.signup(user);
        const { token } = res.data;
        localStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token);
        SessionUtil.setAuthToken(token);
        const decoded = jwt_decode(token);


        dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.LOGIN_USER, payload: decoded });
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.SESSION_ERRORS})
    }

}
```

Types

```
export type LoginInfo = {
    id: any,
    email: string,
    passsword: string
};
<br>
interface ILoginUser {
    type: typeof ActionTypes.LOGIN_USER,
    payload: { currentUser: LoginInfo }
    
};

export type SessionActions =  ILoginUser
```

Store

```
const Store = (preloadedState={}) =>
    createStore(RootReducer, preloadedState, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk, logger)));

export type RootStore = ReturnType<typeof RootReducer>
export default Store;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript error with accessing jwt-decode object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61199530/typescript-error-with-accessing-jwt-decode-object)

Comment: you need to type the `jwt_decode<Loginfo>(token)` if the payload of your token is typed as `LogInfo`. It seems also that `payload : decoded` might be wrong in your dispatch. I guess it should be `payload: {currentUser: decoded}`

Answer (score 0):

Set `strictNullChecks: true` in your tsconfig file.

With `strictNullChecks: true`, test is of type string, and with strictNullChecks: false, test is of type number.

```
type test = unknown extends {} ? number : string;
```