# How to Implement Google Sign in in Angular 2+, with the latest google Identity Services

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-platform, google-signin

Google has deprecated the old JavaScript implementation for Google Sign. We should start using the new Identity services. How to implement this is Angular?

Answer (score 7):

We assume that you already have a Google key for this type of service (Google Client ID) so we proceed to integrate the new Google Sign Identity services in an Angular app.

1. As a good practice, we add to our environment file the variable googleClientId with our Google key mentioned above.

```js
export const environment = {
  ...
  googleClientId: 'YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID',
};
```

2. In the index.html file we add the Google script that will allow us to use this functionality.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  ...
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

3. We install the google one tap types package ([@types/google-one-tap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/google-one-tap)) to help us with the integration (optional).
4. In the component where we are going to use this functionality, in the .ts file we declare the google global variable. In the ngAfterViewInit hook we initialise the button and render it by referring to the id we have assigned to the HTML element where the iframe will be injected. In the initialisation method, the **callback** is where we collect the token that Google returns to us when logging in and we use ngZone because the navigation will be triggered outside Angular zone.

```js
declare var google: any;

import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { accounts } from 'google-one-tap';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-page',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],
})
export class LoginPageComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const gAccounts: accounts = google.accounts;

    gAccounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: environment.googleClientId,
      ux_mode: 'popup',
      cancel_on_tap_outside: true,
      callback: ({ credential }) => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          this._loginWithGoogle(credential);
        });
      },
    });

    gAccounts.id.renderButton(document.getElementById('gbtn') as HTMLElement, {
      size: 'large',
      width: 320,
    });
  }

  private _loginWithGoogle(token: string) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use own button (with own design) for this?

Answer (score 2):

New Client IDs created before July 29th, 2022 can use the older Google Platform Library. By default, [newly created Client IDs](https://www.codingvila.com/2022/07/angular-14-login-with-google-using-oauth.html) are now blocked from using the Platform Library and instead must use the newer Google Identity Services library. You may choose any value, a descriptive name such as product or plugin name is recommended for easy identification.

Example: **plugin_name:** 'login'.

Please Read my article [Angular 14 Login with Google using OAuth 2.0](https://www.codingvila.com/2022/07/angular-14-login-with-google-using-oauth.html) where I explained everything step by step.

```
googleAuthSDK() {

    (<any>window)['googleSDKLoaded'] = () => {
      (<any>window)['gapi'].load('auth2', () => {
        this.auth2 = (<any>window)['gapi'].auth2.init({
          client_id: 'YOUR CLIENT ID',
          plugin_name:'login',
          cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
          scope: 'profile email'
        });
        this.callLogin();
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Google documentation, it has two ways, one using javascript and the other using HTML.

I used HTML to render the button on the page and javascript (typescript to be concise) to import the library into the component and capture the response from Google using a callback function.

### so, on our Login Component:

- in login.component.html

```
    <div id="g_id_onload"
          data-client_id="*********************.apps.googleusercontent.com"
          data-callback="handleCredentialResponse"
          data-auto_prompt="false">
          </div>
    <div class="g_id_signin btn"
            data-type="standard"
            data-size="large"
            data-theme="filled_black"
            data-text="sign_in_with"
            data-shape="rectangular"
            data-logo_alignment="left">
          </div>
```

*please note that the callback function here is "handleCredentialResponse"*

- in login.component.ts

```
    (function (d, s, id) {
      var js, gjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[1];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client";
      gjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, gjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'async defer'));

    (window as any).handleCredentialResponse = (response) => {
      console.log(response);
      if (response && response.credential){
          // handle the response here...
            }
          }, err => {
            console.log(err);
          })
        }
      };
```

For me, I send `response.credential` to the back end server to be validated, but you can decode the response on you Angular App if you want, and for this you can use something like [jwt-decode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode).

Also, if you faced a problem using it into your Angular App, you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61201393/765194).

Comment: I followed this same logic but in this approach, how we can refresh the token after 1 hour? can you share the refresh logic?

Answer (score -1):

1. In Index.html, Paste this script tag under the head tag, like below.

```html
<head>
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer> 
</script>
</head>
```

2. In the html component, add this below code to show google login button.

```html
<div id="googleButton"></div>
```

3. Finally in the ts file, add the below code with your google client ID.

```js
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone)
ngAfterViewInit() {
  google.accounts.id.initialize({
    client_id: "",
    callback: (window as any)['handleCredentialResponse'] = 
     (response: any) => this.ngZone.run(() => {
      console.log("this response holds the token for the logged 
       in user information",response)
    })
  });

  google.accounts.id.renderButton(
    document.getElementById("googleButton"),
    { type: "standard", text: "signin_with", theme: "outline", 
    size: "medium", width: "250"}
  )
}
```

4. In the response, you will be getting a token, you have to decode it to get retrieve the logged in user information, you can probably use 'jwt-decode' package to do so.

```js
    import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
    jwt_decode(response.credential);
```